# Strongwan S2S VPN to Fortinet

Tags: iptables, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan, fortigate, masquerade

I want to hide my local hosted server behind a public VPS. So i established a VPN between my local firewall(fortinet) and my
vps(strongswan).
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNmJV.png)

The VPN is up but no traffic at all. Even in tcpdump i can't see any
traffic coming from the tunnel in both directions.

VPS:

- 92.x.x.x on ens6 (srv1.domain.net)
- 10.200.0.25/29 on ens6:1 (alias IP on Networkdevice with "ip addr add")

Home:

- dynamic IP -> 82.x.x.x on wan1 (home.domain.net)
- 10.1.0.0/20

### VPS

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         93.x.x.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens6
10.200.0.24     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 ens6
93.x.x.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens6
```

ipsec.conf

```
        lifetime=3600s
        ikelifetime=3h
        keyingtries=3
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
        type=tunnel
        auto=start
        mobike=no

        ike=aes128-aes256-sha256-sha384-x25519!
        esp=aes128gcm16-aes256gcm16-x25519!

        leftsubnet=10.200.0.24/29
        left=92.x.x.x
conn home
        right=home.domain.net
        rightsubnet=10.1.0.0/20
```

```
root@ubuntu:~# ipsec status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
        home[1]: ESTABLISHED 93 minutes ago, 93.x.x.x[srv1.domain.net]...88.x.x.x[home.domain.net]
        home{3}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: c1fc6d50_i c502a2f6_o
        home{3}:   10.200.0.24/29 === 10.1.0.0/20       
        
root@ubuntu:~# ip xfrm state          
src 93.x.x.x dst 82.x.x.x
        proto esp spi 0xc502a2f6 reqid 1 mode tunnel
        replay-window 0 flag af-unspec
        aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) 0xxxxxxx 128
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
src 82.x.x.x dst 93.x.x.x
        proto esp spi 0xc1fc6d50 reqid 1 mode tunnel
        replay-window 32 flag af-unspec
        aead rfc4106(gcm(aes)) 0xxxxxxx 128
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000
```

### Ping from 10.1.2.77 to 10.200.0.25

Firewall Fortigate

```
fw # diagnose sniffer packet "S2S-srv1" none 4
interfaces=[S2S-srv1]
filters=[none]
pcap_lookupnet: S2S-srv1: no IPv4 address assigned
4.900617 S2S-srv1 -- 10.1.2.77 -> 10.200.0.25: icmp: echo request
9.866557 S2S-srv1 -- 10.1.2.77 -> 10.200.0.25: icmp: echo request
14.866824 S2S-srv1 -- 10.1.2.77 -> 10.200.0.25: icmp: echo request
19.867489 S2S-srv1 -- 10.1.2.77 -> 10.200.0.25: icmp: echo request
```

VPS

```
root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump -v -n -i any port not 22 and not port 53
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
[empty]
```

### Ping from VPS to 10.1.1.1

Firewall Fortigate

```
fw # diagnose sniffer packet "S2S-srv1" none 4
interfaces=[S2S-srv1]
filters=[none]
pcap_lookupnet: S2S-srv1: no IPv4 address assigned
[empty]
```

VPS

```
root@ubuntu:~# tcpdump -v -n -i any port not 22
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
13:09:47.663917 ens6  Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34394, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ESP (50), length 140)
    93.x.x.x > 88.x.x.x: ESP(spi=0xc502a2f6,seq=0x5), length 120
13:09:48.688043 ens6  Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 34532, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ESP (50), length 140)
    93.x.x.x > 88.x.x.x: ESP(spi=0xc502a2f6,seq=0x6), length 120
```

### Ping from VPS 10.200.0.25 to 10.1.1.1

Firewall Fortigate

```
fw # diagnose sniffer packet "S2S-srv1" none 4
interfaces=[S2S-srv1]
filters=[none]
pcap_lookupnet: S2S-srv1: no IPv4 address assigned
[empty]
```

VPS

```
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
13:14:48.239905 lo    In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 45593, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 92, options (NOP,LSRR 10.1.1.1))
    10.200.0.25 > 10.200.0.25: ICMP echo request, id 15, seq 26, length 64
13:14:49.263958 lo    In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 45646, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 92, options (NOP,LSRR 10.1.1.1))
    10.200.0.25 > 10.200.0.25: ICMP echo request, id 15, seq 27, length 64
```

I believe i need to set some iptables rules....Anybody any hint?